# Tracking GA data for particular URI

Tags: analytics

So I have added this to my GA script ( in footer )

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview' , '<?php $thisurl="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];echo $thisurl; ?>']);
```

My question is , when we look at src code: we see .. ( for our about.php page )

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview' , 'http://www.ourdomain.com/about.php']);
```

Now is this correct protocol, or because setDomainName has already been set to ourdomain.com within GA script ..

Should we echo this instead ?

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview' , '/about.php']);
```

ANy help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**_gaq.push(['_trackPageview' , '/about.php']);** is the right way. See example at Google tutorial:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview